# Windows phone 8.1 crop rectangle

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8.1, crop

I m making windows phone 8.1 app which have crop function. The problem is that i don't know how to make a graphical rectangle that user can resize and than crop image. Image is located on :

```
Image x:Name="ImagePreview" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="492" Margin="10,10,0,0" Stretch="UniformToFill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="380" >
```

Comment: How are you setting source of ImagePreview?

Comment: I m sending picture form first screen where i take photo with camera or select it via gallery . Then i set it when screen for editing is called.


 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
                var obj = App.Current as App;
                original = obj.ImageToEdit;
                ImagePreview.Source = original;
            }


        }

Comment: So ImagePreview source is BitmapImage or WritableBitmap? Because I prepared the solution for croping in Windows10 but its crashing in WP8.1 while creating stream from BitmapImage.

Comment: Image is BitmapImage type

Comment: Aww.. Then wait for a while. I ll try to find the reason for crashing and i'll post the answer. How are you creating obj.ImageToEdit?PLease post the code in your question

Comment: I know, i have same problem with creating stream from BitmapImage when i use RandomAccessStreamReference.  I m creating like this :     var obj = App.Current as App;
                    obj.ImageToEdit = bitmapImage;

Comment: Yeah. You can save StorageFile instead of BitmapImage and use it in second page. You can get IRandomAccessStream from StorageFile easily

Comment: Yes, i m doing that when i save image to phone

Comment: You can refer this link for crash https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/be8eafdc-f880-4186-81da-d1d8dac133f5/storagefilegetfilefromapplicationuriasync-stopped-working-in-release-preview?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: Thank you on link. Can u tell me how to convert WriteableBitmap image to BitmapImage? I had searched all over internet and can't find it.

Comment: Why do you want to convert to bitmapimage? You can assign writablebitmap to image source

Comment: Because of 2 reason. When i call grayScale effect, method make new WriteableBitmap file. Then when i want to save it as bitmap and wrote like this : imageToSave = ImagePreview.Source as BitmapImage; imageToSave is null. But when i set imageToSave = ImagePreview.Source as WriteableBitmap; imageToSave is not null. I need it to be BitmapImage file for later saving on phone. And when try to crop BitmapImage file, app crash because of  BitmapImage file

Comment: For cropping you can just use Writablbitmap. In that case bit of  code reduces in `CropBtn_Click` method where I create `WB_CapturedImage` (which is `Writablebitmap`). you can go ahead and assign  `ImagePreview.Source` to `WB_CapturedImage`

Comment: My whole app works with bitmapImage. Tried working with WriteableBitmap  and i got many problems with crashing. Is there a way to cast WriteableBitmap  to BitmapImage ? It will save me a lot of time and nerves.

Comment: Try this link https://canbilgin.wordpress.com/2012/06/06/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-irandomaccessstream/. I hope you know how to get byte array from Writablebitmap

Comment: Problem is solved. I m converting WriteableBitmap to StoradgeFile and than i can manipulate as i want. Thank you LovetoCode on your help.

Comment: Hi, i m having a little problem. I m creating image with grayScale filter by using StorageFile. The problem starts when i try to set filter on second image. First time i take picture and set filter and its ok, second time when i take picture and try to set filter i got error message : Access is denied. Exception from HRESULT: ...  . Third time when i take pic, i can set filter, fourth time i got error again and so on. I know that problem is that app still use that same StorageFile and its locked, but i don't know how to close that file. Do you have any advice ?

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: First part of creating storadge file:        ImageEncodingProperties imgFormat = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
            InMemoryRandomAccessStream imageStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            await newCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(imgFormat, imageStream);
            BitmapDecoder dec = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(imageStream);
            BitmapEncoder enc = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(imageStream, dec);
await enc.FlushAsync();
string name= "IMG_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".jpg"; name= naziv.Insert(12, "_");

Comment: second part:   file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
                naziv,
                CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            var filestream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
            await RandomAccessStream.CopyAsync(imageStream, filestream);
            BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.Path));

            var obj = App.Current as App;
            obj.fileTransfer = file;    
. GrayScale filter you wrote for me.

Comment: You can Post the code in Question since it has formatting option. In comments its hard to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the xaml for croping image(including croping rectangle)

```
<Grid >
        <ScrollViewer>
            <Grid >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Button Content="Pick a image" Click="Button_Click" />
                <Canvas Grid.Row="1" Width="380" Height="492"  Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Image x:Name="original" ImageOpened="original_ImageOpened" Stretch="Uniform" ManipulationCompleted="Rectangle_ManipulationCompleted" ManipulationDelta="Rectangle_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationStarted="Rectangle_ManipulationStarted" ManipulationMode="All" PointerPressed="rect_PointerPressed" Source="Assets/new_arrivals.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="492" Width="380"  >

                    </Image>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="rect"  StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Red">
                    </Rectangle>
                </Canvas>
                <Button Grid.Row="2" Name="CropBtn" Content="CropImage"  Click="CropBtn_Click" />
                <Image Grid.Row="3" Stretch="None" Name="FinalCroppedImage"/>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

code behind

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        bool pointerpressed = false;
        WriteableBitmap WB_CapturedImage;//for original image
        WriteableBitmap WB_CroppedImage;//for cropped image
        Point Point1, Point2;
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
           // view = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView();
            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
            CompositionTarget.Rendering += CompositionTarget_Rendering;
        }

        void CompositionTarget_Rendering(object sender, object e)
        {
            rect.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, (Point1.X < Point2.X) ? Point1.X : Point2.X);
            rect.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, (Point1.Y < Point2.Y) ? Point1.Y : Point2.Y);
            rect.Width = (int)Math.Abs(Point2.X - Point1.X);
            rect.Height = (int)Math.Abs(Point2.Y - Point1.Y);
        }
    //To generate croping rectangle
    private void Rectangle_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                Point1 = e.Position;//Set first touchable cordinates as point1
                Point2 = Point1;
            }

            private void Rectangle_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                var point = Point2;
                if (e.Position.X <= original.ActualWidth && e.Position.X >= 0)
                    point.X = e.Position.X;
                if (e.Position.Y <= original.ActualHeight && e.Position.Y >= 0)
                    point.Y = e.Position.Y;
                Point2 = point;
            }

            private void Rectangle_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                var point = Point2;
               // Debug.WriteLine(e.Position.X + "&&&" + original.ActualWidth);
                if (e.Position.X <= original.ActualWidth && e.Position.X>=0)
                    point.X = e.Position.X;
                if (e.Position.Y <= original.ActualHeight && e.Position.Y >= 0)
                    point.Y = e.Position.Y;
                Point2 = point;
            }

            private void rect_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                pointerpressed = true;
                Point1 = e.GetCurrentPoint(original).Position;//Set first touchable cordinates as point1
                Point2 = Point1;
            }
 private async void CropBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BitmapDecoder decoder = null;
            BitmapImage bImage = original.Source as BitmapImage;

            if (storageFile == null && bImage.UriSource!=null)
            {
                storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx://"+bImage.UriSource.AbsolutePath));
            }

            using (IRandomAccessStream streamWithContent = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            {        
                decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(streamWithContent);
                BitmapFrame bitmapFrame = await decoder.GetFrameAsync(0);
                WB_CapturedImage = new WriteableBitmap((int)bitmapFrame.PixelWidth,
                                                             (int)bitmapFrame.PixelHeight);
                Size cropsize = new Size(Math.Abs(Point2.X - Point1.X), Math.Abs(Point2.Y - Point1.Y));
                double originalImageWidth = WB_CapturedImage.PixelWidth;
                double originalImageHeight = WB_CapturedImage.PixelHeight;

                // Get the size of the image when it is displayed on the phone
                double displayedWidth = original.ActualWidth;
                double displayedHeight = original.ActualHeight;

                // Calculate the ratio of the original image to the displayed image
                double widthRatio = originalImageWidth / displayedWidth;
                double heightRatio = originalImageHeight / displayedHeight;
                WB_CroppedImage = await GetCroppedBitmapAsync(streamWithContent, Point1, cropsize, widthRatio, heightRatio);

                FinalCroppedImage.Source = WB_CroppedImage;
            }
        }
 public static async Task<WriteableBitmap> GetCroppedBitmapAsync(IRandomAccessStream originalImage,
       Point startPoint, Size cropSize, double scaleWidth, double scaleheight)
    {
        if (double.IsNaN(scaleWidth) || double.IsInfinity(scaleWidth))
        {
            scaleWidth = 1;
        }
        if (double.IsNaN(scaleheight) || double.IsInfinity(scaleheight))
        {
            scaleheight = 1;
        }
        // Convert start point and size to integer.
        var startPointX = (uint)Math.Floor(startPoint.X * scaleWidth);
        var startPointY = (uint)Math.Floor(startPoint.Y * scaleheight);
        var height = (uint)Math.Floor(cropSize.Height * scaleheight);
        var width = (uint)Math.Floor(cropSize.Width * scaleWidth);

        // Create a decoder from the stream. With the decoder, we can get 
        // the properties of the image.
        var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(originalImage);

        // The scaledSize of original image.
        var scaledWidth = (uint)(decoder.PixelWidth);
        var scaledHeight = (uint)(decoder.PixelHeight);

        // Refine the start point and the size. 
        if (startPointX + width > scaledWidth)
        {
            startPointX = scaledWidth - width;
        }

        if (startPointY + height > scaledHeight)
        {
            startPointY = scaledHeight - height;
        }

        // Get the cropped pixels.
        var pixels = await GetPixelData(decoder, startPointX, startPointY, width, height,
            scaledWidth, scaledHeight);

        // Stream the bytes into a WriteableBitmap
        var cropBmp = new WriteableBitmap((int)width, (int)height);
        var pixStream = cropBmp.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
        pixStream.Write(pixels, 0, (int)(width * height * 4));

        return cropBmp;
    }

 private static async Task<byte[]> GetPixelData(BitmapDecoder decoder, uint startPointX, uint startPointY,
          uint width, uint height, uint scaledWidth, uint scaledHeight)
        {
            var transform = new BitmapTransform();
            var bounds = new BitmapBounds();
            bounds.X = startPointX;
            bounds.Y = startPointY;
            bounds.Height = height;
            bounds.Width = width;
            transform.Bounds = bounds;

            transform.ScaledWidth = scaledWidth;
            transform.ScaledHeight = scaledHeight;

            // Get the cropped pixels within the bounds of transform.
            var pix = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(
                BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
                transform,
                ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation,
                ColorManagementMode.ColorManageToSRgb);
            var pixels = pix.DetachPixelData();
            return pixels;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have published a sample Windows 10 application which offer crop capabilities on images. Most of the code can be reused in Windows Phone 8.1.

The control is here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/Appsample-Photosharing/blob/master/PhotoSharingApp/PhotoSharingApp.Universal/Controls/CropControl.cs

And it is used in the following page:
https://github.com/Microsoft/Appsample-Photosharing/blob/master/PhotoSharingApp/PhotoSharingApp.Universal/Views/CropPage.xaml

You also have to check the template declared in (search for controls:CropControl):
https://github.com/Microsoft/Appsample-Photosharing/blob/master/PhotoSharingApp/PhotoSharingApp.Universal/Styles/Styles.xaml